# I want to download a file from a WebView

Tags: java, android

I want to download a file from Android's WebView, but I'm in trouble.
If the file you want to download is a file that can only be downloaded after logging in to the site, how should I write the process? (It will be displayed when you can not access if you directly step the URL)

Currently I write such a process.

■ Situation

1. Setting around the authority of reading and writing is over.
2. You can download it by rewriting the url variable to an image of a web page that anyone can download freely and then test it
3. If you try to download as it is, the download will fail.

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                String filename = "test";
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                request.setMimeType(mimetype);

                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(android.content.Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);


            }
        });
```

It is a situation like It would be very helpful if you could tell me if there was a cause

Comment: and ... what is your actual problem?

Comment: What is the problem with `DownloadManager`?